# applying alternate row color CSS for laravel table

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

How can I apply alternate row color CSS in laravel table. i want to display alternate color for the table rows. I've kept gridview cssclass in the table. I want to apply `.gridview tr.even td` for the even row count i.e. the rows with multiple of 2.

My CSS file

```
.gridview {
    font-family: "arial";
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: small;
}

    .gridview th {
        background: #0CA3D2;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: small;
    }

    .gridview td {
        background: #B6E1EE;
        color: #333333;
        font: small "arial";
        padding: 4px;
    }

    .gridview tr.even td {
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Table code

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered gridview">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BOOK ID</th>
                    <th>BILLED DATE</th>                      
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                @foreach($ordered_books as $data)
                 <tr>
                     <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>                         
                     <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td>
                 </tr>
                @endforeach
          </tbody>          
        </table>
```

Comment: if it is just css then perhaps `.gridview tr:nth-of-type( even ) td{/* definitions */}`

Comment: @RamRaider please show me the code, how to implement it `.gridview tr:nth-of-type( even ) td{/* definitions */}`. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@RamRaider has the best suggestion of using css. Another way is using the modulus operator:

```
@foreach($ordered_books as $i => $data) 
    @php $class = $i ÷ 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'; @endphp
    <tr class="{{ $class }}"> 
        <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>
        <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td> 
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to play with css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) td {
   background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

For odd tr:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
   background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered gridview" style="color:{{ !is_null(user()) ? 'red' : 'green' }}">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BOOK ID</th>
                <th>BILLED DATE</th>                      
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            @foreach($ordered_books as $data)
             <tr>
                 <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>                         
                 <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td>
             </tr>
            @endforeach
      </tbody>          
    </table>
```

It is example with php, but i think that the best way to do this with js

Comment: I've added more explanation.